# Comparing two dataframes with same data from two different sources fails

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, postgresql, hana

I have created a Pandas dataframe from Hana using pyhdb library and Created another dataframe from PostgreSQL using Psycopg2. Both of them have same data like same numbers of rows and columns and sorted in way. Both of them have 5 rows and 5 columns. If I use df1 == df2,it shows False for everything. If I use the below function, it don't return anything for `dataframe_difference(df1, df2, 'both')`. I tried `df1.equals(df2)`. This is False as well.

```
def dataframe_difference(df1, df2, which=None):
    """Find rows which are different between two DataFrames."""
    comparison_df = df1.merge(df2,
                              indicator=True,
                              how='outer')
    if which is None:
        diff_df = comparison_df[comparison_df['_merge'] != 'both']
    else:
        diff_df = comparison_df[comparison_df['_merge'] == which]
    diff_df.to_csv('diff.csv')
    return diff_df
```

Now I write both df1 and df2 to csv and read them again, and I tried all the above methods to check equality. Now everything is True. Is there any reason it won't work in the first scenario. If Yes, how to solve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The following method shows the differences and its reason so it might help for debugging.

```
from pandas.util.testing import assert_frame_equal
assert_frame_equal(df1, df2) or 
assert_frame_equal(df1, df2, check_dtype=False)
```

Comment: I tried the above stuff. Here is the error.

AssertionError: DataFrame.iloc[:, 0] are different

DataFrame.iloc[:, 0] values are different (100.0 %) 
[left]:  [525, 525, 525, 525, 525] 
[right]: [525, 525, 525, 525, 525]

Comment: did you try the one with check_dtype?

Comment: Indices of dfs might be different. Could you also try with the following argument, check_index_type=False ?

Comment: Tried assert_frame_equal(df1,df2,check_index_type=False,check_dtype=False), Still same issue.

Comment: Is it possible to share a small sample of your dataset I can investigate?

Comment: I can provide in CSV file, but csv file comparison is working good, the only problem is not able validate dataframes from two different db's

Comment: If there is anything that you think I could work on or can be helpful, please share it. I would like to help.

Comment: Thank You very much. I'm didn't understand the how to resolve this. I'll let you know if i find any work around.